# Non-degeneracy of the ground states of quantum spin models

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, many-body, spin-models, ground-state

It is known that the ground state of some quantum spin models is non-degenerate. For example, the ground states of the quantum Ising model and the ferromagnetic Heisenberg model on the subspace of a fixed value of the z-component of the total spin are non-degenerate. For certainty, the Hamiltonian operators of these models are written as
$$
\hat{H}_{qI} = -h\sum_j \hat{S}_j^x - \frac12\sum_{i,j}J_{i,j}\ \hat{S}^z_i\hat{S}^z_j
$$
and
$$
\hat{H}_{Heis} = -\frac12\sum_{i,j} J_{i,j}\ \hat{\vec{S}}_i \hat{\vec{S}}_j,\quad J_{i,j} \geq 0.
$$
I have a strong feeling that the non-degeneracy property of the ground states in these cases is a consequence of some theorem. Alas, I have not seen any references to such a theorem in the books and articles I have read. Can someone help and give a link where such a theorem is mentioned?

For the case of the Schrodinger equation for a particle in a potential well, such a theorem is well known. See, for example, the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27016/non-degeneracy-of-ground-state-in-quantum-mechanics)

**Update.** Response to NorbertSchuch's comments. My question is about finite-size systems. Otherwise, I would not say that the ground state of the quantum Ising model is non-degenerate. The Heisenberg ferromagnetic model is discussed in this [book](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/2945#t=aboutBook). The model with the interaction of the nearest neighbors is discussed there on pages 265-266. I think the same arguments are valid for the general ferromagnetic Heisenberg model. For the case when $\hat{S}^\alpha_j$ are spin-s operators, the statement is made that the ground state of the ferromagnetic Heisenberg model is $2sN+1$-fold degenerate, where $N$ is the number of spins. This number coincides with the number of possible different values of $z$-component of total spin, $S^z_{tot}$. Therefore I think that the ground state of the finite-size ferromagnetic Heisenberg model is non-degenerate at a fixed $S^z_{tot}$.

The question of what properties of the Heisenberg and Ising model lead to non-degeneracy of the ground state can be considered as part of my question. Although, after looking at the link provided by Tobias Funke, I think that this feature is the non-positivity of elements and irreducibility of the non-diagonal part of the Hamiltonian operator in some basis. Then a previously unknown to me version of the Perron Frobenius theorem is applied. I didn't know before about generalization of this theorem to the case of matrices whose elements can be zero.

Comment: Not the models you asked, but do you ask something along these lines: *Ground states of the spin-1 bose-hubbard model. Katsura and Tasaki. PRL. 2013? Perhaps the references given there, and articles citing this work, can also be a good starting point.

Comment: The work of E. Lieb is probably worth to study.

Comment: @TobiasFünke many thanks for the reference! The question of the uniqueness of the ground state is really considered in this article. And the authors reduce the formulation and proof of non-degeneracy to a variation of the Perron-Frobenius theorem. Not entirely unexpected, but I thought there might be more to it. Something more specific to quantum spin systems with other names.

Comment: Most probably, the Lieb-Schultz-Mattis (LSM) theorem is the answer to your question.

Comment: What kind of theorem? What properties of the model should it use? This question does not seem to make much sense in this form, unless you think there is the one famous theorem you forgot about (but then again, what does it require?). Not to mention that the Heisenberg model might have a unique ground state, but is gapless, so the "non-degenerate ground state" statement does not really work for infinite chains. (In fact, I would be sceptical that your claim about the Heisenberg model is even correct on arbitrary graphs and general positive coupling $J_{ij}$.)

Comment: @Mass LSM shows that a model is gapless (or has degenerate ground states), not the opposite as being asked here.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch my answer is above

Comment: @Gec Oh, I overlooked that you have a ferromagnet. Then it is *exactly* degenerate; in particular, all states $\lvert\phi\rangle^{\otimes N}$ are ground states. The restriction to fixed Sz seems a bit ad hoc then; there is always some restriction (to a symmetry sector) which will make the ground state non-degenerate, unless for very special, fine-tuned, models.